# Can the salary be negotiated after receiving the offer letter?

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation

I've received an offer letter but I feel the salary is lower than I expected. I am currently in my notice period with my previous employer.

Can I renegotiate my salary without jeopardizing the job offer?

Comment: Did you verbally accept the offer? If so, you may be stuck where you are unless you are rejecting the offer. Renegotiating is likely to go over badly if you'd already said you come work for the rate stated.

Comment: Not verbally but they give me the photo copy of offer letter, not original document, they told me to send me the original in email,But I think I can discus with company regarding salary

Comment: While I suppose there isn't anything illegal about wanting to discuss salary still, I suspect if you do want to negotiate further the company may take back their offer as you could be seen as "difficult to work with"

Comment: Actually the company is in different city from my home so I ready to relocate there but I dont have an idea how much the accommodation exp. later on I calculate every things & found that It might difficult to me to work in that amount of salary,pulse point is that my tech interview was A+

Answer (score 12):

> can i still discuss with HR for salary

Since you haven't signed the offer, then you can still discuss the details, and perhaps have them changed.

It's unfortunate that you have already negotiated to the point where you got an offer letter with a 7 day turnaround period. Better would be to have negotiated your desired salary first. But it's still possible to continue the negotiation up until the point where you sign the offer.

Don't wait. Contact HR and tell them that after thinking about it more, you believe the offer is too low. Be prepared to give reasons why you feel that way. And be prepared to explain why you didn't give those reasons earlier in the negotiations.

> If I negotiate with HR can my dream job in lose ?

Yes of course. That's the way negotiations work. Until you sign the offer letter the company can withdraw it at any time, for any reason. (They can do so later as well, but that's a different discussion).

You need to negotiate carefully here. The company may have another candidate that is almost as good as you are, or they may not. The company may feel that you are not worth the effort of negotiating further, or they may be willing to play along up to a point.

There's no real way for you to know how far they are willing to go unless you push them past that point.

You have to decide how much of a dream job this is, how much you really need in salary, and how much you are willing to risk.

Comment: "It's unfortunate that you have already negotiated to the point where you got an offer letter ..." While it seems strange, I've had a couple experiences where the companies wouldn't negotiate until they had sent their offer letter, even though I had told them verbally that the offer would not be acceptable. Only after the letter had been rejected in writing (email) with something like "The job is appealing, but that offer is unacceptable, Instead I'd join you for (*my counter offer*)." did they find a way to negotiate.

Comment: Yes, it was odd. In the case that really stood out, I think the HR person thought I was bluffing or that they could bamboozle me into accepting that initial offer (even though the salary and benefits were virtually equal to what I was already getting) ... or wasn't authorized to negotiate and was unable at the time (or too lazy) to move things up the chain to someone who could.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes

When I accepted my current job a number for salary wasn't discussed until I got the offer letter.  I then countered back that I needed more and they sent me a new letter with a higher salary.

There's always a chance they could say no, they most likely wont withdraw the offer.