# Can you renegotiate your salary after signing an offer letter?

Tags: salary

I signed an offer letter but later realized that an annual performance bonus is not issued by the company nor is profit sharing. Companies that I have worked in the past provide a performance bonus at the end of the year which was 10% of your base salary. 
Can I request that my base salary be increased to accommodate for the lack of a company performance bounus? I signed the offer letter 10-28-14 and scheduled to start work 11-11-14

Comment: You can ask but if I were the hiring offical, I would rescind the offer. Asking for 10% more after signing the letter is simply unprofessional. Let this be a lesson to you that you have to read the offer carefully before you accept.

Comment: Related: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21098/can-the-salary-be-negotiated-after-receiving-the-offer-letter (There the offer letter was received, but not signed yet)

Comment: what ... what are you trying to achieve with your latest edit?

Comment: Agreed; that edit makes this (a) Not A Question and (b) certainly not the question we answered. Revert it to the original text, and if you have something else you want to know start a new question.

Comment: Why did you so drastically edit the post? You know anyone can see the edit history, right?

Comment: what exactly are you asking here the difference between hourly paid and salaried or how companies budget for their pay ?

Comment: I've rolled back the edit because it leaves us with something that's not a question and it appears to invalidate existing answers.  While, for a question that's already on hold or closed, sometimes the only way to fix the question is to affect existing answers, that needs to be the last resort.

Answer (score 10):

You can ask for anything.

However, the time has passed for negotiation when you signed the offer. An offer was made and accepted and to come in after the fact would likely cause very negative feelings toward you.

Should you ask? In my opinion, absolutely not. It will send the message that you are either unreliable or that you don't pay attention to details.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Had the same thoughts, but was hoping that I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can ask, and it wouldn't be out of order to state the reasons you have stated here. I wouldn't hold out any great hopes of an increase, but unlikely anyone would hold it against you.

Comment: That's the type of thing you should have brought up during the interview process. If your industry average is 100K, but you're getting 90K with 10 years experience, you may need to hone your negotiation skills.